# cannot run Java EE examples from oracle tutorial

Tags: java, maven, jakarta-ee, glassfish

I am reading [oracle's java ee tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/index.html) and I wanted to run the ejb examples that are included in [java ee sdk](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javaee/downloads/index.html). I downloaded what necessary and tried to build the first ejb example 'converter' - running from command line, in netbeans 8.2 and in eclipse as a maven build (I had to give target 'install'). Each time I get the same error which is:

```
Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.cargo:cargo-maven2-plugin:1.6.9:redeploy (deploy) on project converter: Execution deploy of goal org.codehaus.cargo:cargo-maven2-plugin:1.6.9:redeploy failed: GlassFish admin command with args (--interactive=false --host localhost --port 4848 --user admin --passwordfile d:\glassfish5\glassfish\domains\password.properties deploy --force --contextroot converter D:\glassfish5\docs\javaee-tutorial\examples\ejb\converter\target\converter.war) failed: asadmin exited 1 -> [Help 1]

To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
```

I have tried all the solutions that I found here on stackoverflow.com and other websites - nothing helped. I know nothing about maven. Can anybody help?

Running mvn install -X gives this:

```
    [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.cargo:cargo-maven2-plugin:1.6.9:redeploy (deploy) on project converter: Execution deploy of goal org.codehaus.cargo:cargo-maven2-plugin:1.6.9:redeploy failed: GlassFish admin command with args (--interactive=false --host localhost --port 4848 --user admin --passwordfile d:\glassfish5\glassfish\domains\password.properties deploy --force --contextroot converter D:\glassfish5\docs\javaee-tutorial\examples\ejb\converter\target\converter.war) failed: asadmin exited 1 -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.cargo:cargo-maven2-plugin:1.6.9:redeploy (deploy) on project converter: Execution deploy of goal org.codehaus.cargo:cargo-maven2-plugin:1.6.9:redeploy failed: GlassFish admin command with args (--interactive=false --host localhost --port 4848 --user admin --passwordfile d:\glassfish5\glassfish\domains\password.properties deploy --force --contextroot converter D:\glassfish5\docs\javaee-tutorial\examples\ejb\converter\target\converter.war) failed: asadmin exited 1
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:213)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:154)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:146)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:954)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:192)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.PluginExecutionException: Execution deploy of goal org.codehaus.cargo:cargo-maven2-plugin:1.6.9:redeploy failed: GlassFish admin command with args (--interactive=false --host localhost --port 4848 --user admin --passwordfile d:\glassfish5\glassfish\domains\password.properties deploy --force --contextroot converter D:\glassfish5\docs\javaee-tutorial\examples\ejb\converter\target\converter.war) failed: asadmin exited 1
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:208)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:154)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:146)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:954)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:192)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.codehaus.cargo.util.CargoException: GlassFish admin command with args (--interactive=false --host localhost --port 4848 --user admin --passwordfile d:\glassfish5\glassfish\domains\password.properties deploy --force --contextroot converter D:\glassfish5\docs\javaee-tutorial\examples\ejb\converter\target\converter.war) failed: asadmin exited 1
    at org.codehaus.cargo.container.glassfish.internal.GlassFish3xAsAdmin.invokeAsAdmin (GlassFish3xAsAdmin.java:98)
    at org.codehaus.cargo.container.glassfish.internal.AbstractGlassFishInstalledLocalContainer.invokeAsAdmin (AbstractGlassFishInstalledLocalContainer.java:96)
    at org.codehaus.cargo.container.glassfish.internal.AbstractGlassFishInstalledLocalContainer.invokeAsAdmin (AbstractGlassFishInstalledLocalContainer.java:69)
    at org.codehaus.cargo.container.glassfish.GlassFish3xInstalledLocalDeployer.doDeploy (GlassFish3xInstalledLocalDeployer.java:110)
    at org.codehaus.cargo.container.glassfish.internal.AbstractGlassFishInstalledLocalDeployer.redeploy (AbstractGlassFishInstalledLocalDeployer.java:99)
    at org.codehaus.cargo.maven2.DeployerRedeployMojo.performDeployerActionOnSingleDeployable (DeployerRedeployMojo.java:46)
    at org.codehaus.cargo.maven2.AbstractDeployerMojo.performDeployerActionOnAllDeployables (AbstractDeployerMojo.java:179)
    at org.codehaus.cargo.maven2.AbstractDeployerMojo.doExecute (AbstractDeployerMojo.java:96)
    at org.codehaus.cargo.maven2.AbstractCargoMojo.execute (AbstractCargoMojo.java:471)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:208)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:154)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:146)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:954)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:192)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:356)
[ERROR]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginExecutionException
```

Comment: Did you Re-run Maven using the -X ? can you add the full exception?

Comment: I updated the question with the output I get when I run mvn install -X

Comment: It looks like it's complaining that it can't login to glassfish to deploy - I'd verify you have the correct credentials

Comment: one of the suggested solutions I had found on stackoverflow included setting a password in password.properties. I worked fine in netbeans after I removed the password.